# Change id according to the number of objects in an array (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, javascript-objects

From a form I can insert "name", "surname", "age" and then I print them in a table immediately below the form.

Everytime I add a user, I append a row and I push every information in an array.

I have a variable called "idUser" that I use to give to each row a unique id: first row id=0, second row id=1, third row id=2 etc so each time I increment the "idUser" variable and I assign it to the new row.

Then I can edit and delete every row, but I don't know how to solve a problem: 
for example I have 3 users, so I print

```
idUser=0 name surname age edit delete
idUser=1 name surname age edit delete
idUser=2 name surname age edit delete
```

and I have this array with 3 elements:

```
[{
"id": 0,
"name": name,
"surname": surname,
"age": age
},
{
"id": 1,
"name": name,
"surname": surname,
"age": age
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": name,
"surname": surname,
"age": age
},
]
```

If i delete the first row, I delete at the same time the first element in array. So the situation now is:

```
idUser=1 name surname age edit delete
idUser=2 name surname age edit delete
```

and the array:

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": name,
"surname": surname,
"age": age
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": name,
"surname": surname,
"age": age
},
]
```

So I have a lot of problems: if I add a new user, the "idUser" increments so I'll have a new row with id=3

```
idUser=1 name surname age edit delete
idUser=2 name surname age edit delete
idUser=3 name surname age edit delete
```

but if I want to edit the row with idUser=3, I have an error, because I take the information from the array and copy them in the form fields (so I can edit them in the form), but the array has just 3 element (and I ask for the fourth element, because idUser=3, so 4th element in array)....also I should change the id of every object in array (the object in first position [0] has to have id:0, second object id:1). So when I delete something I need to update the id of all objects in array, id in each row and also the variable "idUser"..Idk how to update all this stuff at the same time..it isn't a problem of code, I just need an idea to solve it and how I should handle the id and variable "idUser"

Comment: Instead of trying to access the row by id, try adding the id to a `data-` attribute on the edit link or using traversal functions from the click handler: `var recordId = $(this).closest('tr').find('.record-id').val();`

Comment: but how can I take the data from the array, if I don't use the id? I want to have the id because I can use it to extract data from a specific position in the array...that's why I thought about the incremental variable "idUser"

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `id` property like an index, which will indeed no longer work when you remove elements from your data array. Instead of modifying all data points once an item is removed, I would do one of two things:

- Make a `Map` or `object` that references users by id
- Make a function that finds a user object by id in an array.

For large data sets, I'd go with option 1. But for small arrays, you might as well use `Array.prototype.find` like so:

```js
function getObjWithKeyValue(arr, key, value) {
   return arr.find(function(item) {
     return item[key] === value;
   });
};
                   
var data =  [{id:1,name:"",surname:"",age:""},{id:2,name:"",surname:"",age:""}];

var personWithId1 = getObjWithKeyValue(data, "id", 1);
console.log(personWithId1);
```

---

*The other approach, if you're interested:*

```js
var data =  [{id:1,name:"",surname:"",age:""},{id:2,name:"",surname:"",age:""}];

var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, d) {
  map[d.id] = d;
  return map;
}, {});

var userWithId1 = dataMap[1];
console.log(userWithId1);
```